# How to share specific image from a image list

Tags: html, facebook, twitter

I am working on a photography site which is in progress. It shows photos by an author all aligned in a list form. I want to add a functionality to share particular images to social networks either on hover sharing buttons popup or via floating share which is fixed all times to left of image gallery.

It is easy to share whole list on social networks but I am unable to share specific image. I have my sharing buttons as div ready and working.

How to add this functionality or from where can I start?

Thanks

Comment: I am not getting it, why do you downvote question. I searched Google alot after finding nothing I came here to ask.

Comment: I suppose because this question is not php or javascript, is html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do a "share button" you have to specify the url you are sharing, if you want to share only a image of the page, you have to put the url of the image.

Is better doing a page with the image, because some social networks get the title and the description from the page itself, others you can pass the info.

NOTE: the webpage you are sharing has to be urlencoded.

example for facebook:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fpage.php">Share on facebook!</a>
```

All the social networks has an help page explaining how to create buttons to share.